# Writing a Jagged Array in HDF5 using the Java Native Library

Tags: java, arrays, hdf5, jagged-arrays, hdf

I have tried numerous ways and followed some of the examples that are scattered around the web on how to write a jagged array (an array of arrays that may be of differing lengths) in HDF5.

Most of the examples are in C and rather low-level. Anyhow I can't seem to get it working and I just looked at the C-source code and it pretty much says that any variable-length datatypes that are not strings are not supported (if I understood correctly).

My miserable dysfunctional code (as is):

```java
 public void WIP_createVLenFloatDataSet( List<? extends Number> floats ) throws Exception
  {
    String group = "/test";
    long groupId = createGroupIfNotExist( group );
    MDataQualifier qualifier = new MDataQualifierImpl( group, "float", "0.0.0" );
    long datasetId = openDataSet( qualifier );
    long heapType = H5.H5Tcopy( MDataType.FLOAT_ARRAY.getHDFType() );
    heapType = H5.H5Tvlen_create( heapType );
//    heapType = H5.H5Tarray_create( heapType, 1, new long[]{1} );
    if( !exists( datasetId ) )
    {

      long[] maxDims = new long[]{ HDF5Constants.H5S_UNLIMITED };
      long dataspaceId = H5.H5Screate_simple( 1, new long[]{ 1 }, null );
      // Create the dataset.
      long datasetId1 = -1;
      try
      {
        if( exists( m_fileId ) && exists( dataspaceId ) && exists( heapType ) )
        {
          long creationProperties = H5.H5Pcreate( HDF5Constants.H5P_DATASET_CREATE );
          H5.H5Pset_chunk( creationProperties, /*ndims*/1, new long[]{ 1 } );
          datasetId1 = H5.H5Dcreate( groupId, qualifier.getVersionedName(), heapType, dataspaceId, H5P_DEFAULT, creationProperties, H5P_DEFAULT );
          //          H5.H5Pclose( creationProperties );
        }
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
        LOG.error( "Problems creating the dataset: " + e.getMessage(), e );
      }
      datasetId = datasetId1;
      if( exists( datasetId ) )
      {
        //        flushIfNecessary();
        LOG.trace( "Wrote empty dataset {}", qualifier.getVersionedName() );
      }
    }
    List<? extends Number> data = ( List<? extends Number> )floats;
    //              H5.H5Dwrite( datasetId, heapType, dataspaceId, memSpaceId, HDF5Constants.H5P_DEFAULT, Floats.toArray( data) );
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate( data.size() * 4 );
    floats.forEach( f -> bb.putFloat( f.floatValue() ) );
//    H5.H5Dwrite( datasetId, heapType, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, Floats.toArray( data ) );
    H5.H5Dwrite( datasetId, heapType, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, bb.array() );

  }
```

Has anyone done this before and can at least confirm that it's not possible?
The most I can get out of HDF5 is the message "buf does not support variable length type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the "glue code" of the JNI wrapper doesn't support this. If you want to use this feature you either have to implement your own JNI or wait for a newer version. The official JNI code is open source and can be found [here](https://bitbucket.hdfgroup.org/projects/HDFFV/repos/hdf5/browse/java/src/jni/h5dImp.c).